Metic subscription/pull_request_count not available via Java client
I can see that when the subscription is pulled by dataflow subscription/pull_request_count is reported correctly. It is also working when I make a pull from GCP console. We use java library https://docs.quarkiverse.io/quarkus-google-cloud-services/main/pubsub.html that is using google api. When subscriptions are pulled using this lib it this metric is not presented. Is there any specific setup that should be done for it?
Deployment of java app, that connects to pubsub subscription. Expected that metric subscription/pull_request_count is reported and is not zero.
